# PHP preg_replace expect digits after a dash

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hi i'm trying to replace all digits or numbers in a string except digits after dash by blank space

For example I have this :

`$string = "1234 Example-1234";`

And I want to have only "Example-1234"

I tried `preg_replace('/\-?\d+/','',$string);` but even digits after dash are replaced

Edited: Thanks everyone i tried all of your answers and it works well !

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for words that **contain** a dash, you can achieve this by to splitting the string via spaces, loop through the array values until you find a string with a dash, and then output from there onwards.

```
$string = "1234 Example-1234";
$words = explode(" ", $string);

foreach($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($word, '-') !== false) {
        echo $word;
        break; // delete this line if there are multiple instances of words with dashes in your string
    }
}
```

This will output `Example-1234`.

You can see a [working example here](https://eval.in/825238)

Comment: And if there's no word `Example`?

Comment: @u_mulder This will still work, I meant that because he's looking for complete words that **contain** a dash. Thanks for pointing out my confusing explanation - am adjusting it now to make more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just skip all digits preceded with `-` and remove all others, use

```
'~-\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Qunil/1)

Note you would like to trim the result or add `\s*` around `\d+` pattern.

**Pattern details**:

- `-\d+(*SKIP)(*F)` - match `-`, 1+ digits and skip this match
- `|` - or
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/ih58bX):

```
$str = '1234 Example-1234';
$res = preg_replace('/-\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*\d+/', '', $str);
echo trim($res); // => Example-1234
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using regex *negative lookbehind assertion* `(?<!a)b`:

```
$str = "1234 Example-1234";
$str = preg_replace('/(?<![0-9-])\d+/', '', $str);    

print_r($str);
```

The output:

```
Example-1234
```

Answer (score 0):

> **ONLINE Regex tester :** https://regex101.com/r/ykUWfM/3

```
<?php

$string = "1234 Example-1234";

echo preg_replace('/-(\d+)/','',$string);

?>
```

> **OUTPUT:**  before `-` convert into string

```
1234 Example
```

NOTE:    Before `-` its get the string before `dash -`

> **OR**

---

> **Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/ykUWfM/2

```
<?php

$string = "1234 Example-1234";

echo preg_replace('/(?<![0-9-])\s*\d+/','',$string);

?>
```

> **OUTPUT:**

```
Example-1234
```